# unexpedtedly close application

Tags: java, android, xml

When i run my application i get unfortunately stop app message, following is my code. Please take a look.

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.dublayout);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                        getAbsolutePath() + "/javacodegeeksRecording.3gpp";

                myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
                myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                addListenerButton();
    }


        private void addListenerButton() {
                    recbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.recbut);
                    recbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          start(v);
                      }
                    });

        }
public void start(View view){
               if (recbtn.getText() == getString(R.string.recBtn)){

                try {
                  myRecorder.prepare();
                  myRecorder.start();
                  recbtn.setText(getString(R.string.stopBtn));
               } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                  // start:it is called before prepare()
                  // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat()
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   // prepare() fails
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else{
                  try {
                      myRecorder.stop();
                      myRecorder.release();
                      myRecorder  = null;
                     recbtn.setText(getString(R.string.recBtn)); 
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        //  it is called before start()
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        // no valid audio/video data has been received
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
```

it is not recording i tried everything still i cannot get it working sorry but i am still new to this kind of language.

In logcat it says:

> 02-05 08:01:09.853: D/OpenGLRenderer(1565): TextureCache::get: create
>   texture(0xb87af490): name, size, mSize = 22, 9216, 9149524 02-05
>   08:01:19.125: E/MediaRecorder(1565): stop called in an invalid state:
>   4 02-05 08:01:19.125: W/System.err(1565):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException 02-05 08:01:19.129:
>   W/System.err(1565):   at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native
>   Method) 02-05 08:01:19.129: W/System.err(1565):   at
>   com.example.mixpad.DubActivity.start(DubActivity.java:136) 02-05
>   08:01:19.129: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   com.example.mixpad.DubActivity$2.onClick(DubActivity.java:99) 02-05
>   08:01:19.129: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 02-05 08:01:19.133:
>   W/System.err(1565):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 02-05
>   08:01:19.137: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 02-05
>   08:01:19.137: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 02-05
>   08:01:19.141: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-05 08:01:19.141:
>   W/System.err(1565):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 02-05
>   08:01:19.141: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-05
>   08:01:19.145: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-05 08:01:19.145:
>   W/System.err(1565):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   02-05 08:01:19.145: W/System.err(1565):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 02-05
>   08:01:19.149: W/System.err(1565):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

can anyone help please

Comment: are you pressing other buttons before rec?

Comment: Please post your full logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `start(...)` method...

```
if (recbtn.getText() == getString(R.string.recBtn))
```

You can't compare strings in Java using `==`. You need to use `equals(...)`.

Your problem is using `==` will always fail which means the `else` condition will always be called and `myRecorder.stop();` will throw the `IllegalStateException` as your `MediaRecorder` has never been prepared / started.

Change that line to...

```
if (recbtn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.recBtn)))
```

Comment: the code if (recbtn.getText().equals(getString(R.string.recBtn))) doesnt work but when ireplace the else it work